# Change onclick function in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

the code below is used to change the onclick event when pressed, however it only alters the function of the parameter, which it simply will not do.

```
function addWhere(nameID)
{
    document.getElementById('addWhereButton').setAttribute("onclick",addWhere(nameID++), false);

    document.getElementById('addWhereButton').onclick = function () {addWhere(nameID++)};
}
```

neither code works and no one else seems to have asked this specific questions before.

Thanks

EDIT

Further testing shows something complete bizarre, a bit of code to display the nameID like so

```
document.getElementById('Testing').innerHTML = nameID++;
```

shows that nameID is actually getting incremented, but the number passed by the onclick never changes.

Comment: Problem is, you're defining the onclick attribute inside the function that defines the onclick. You want to define it OUTSIDE the function someplace, or it never gets applied.

Comment: can you clarify that, I have to define it inside the function because that's where the increment happens.

Comment: Do you have an addWhereButton that has already had its onclick set to this function? If you are expecting this function to point the #addWhereButton to the addWhere function, it never actually SEES that. You'd need to create an initial call to this addWhere function for it to work.

Comment: The simple problem which you didn't explain well. What is *"however it only alters the function of the parameter, which it simply will not do."* supposed to mean?

Comment: so what your saying is that I need to put in a function that points the AddWhereButton to this function with the initial value

Comment: @dfsq if you look at the code, it deosn't change the function the onclick uses, only the parameter, that is going from addWhere(1) to addWhere(2)

Comment: What's the `,false)` for?

Answer (score 1):

Like:

```js
function addWhere(nameID) {
      console.log(nameID);
    };

    let nameID = 1;
    document.getElementById('addWhereButton').onclick = function () {addWhere(nameID++)};
```

```html
<button id="addWhereButton">click to increment nameID</button>
```

Comment: having tried it, it complains that it can't set onclick property of null.

Comment: also the code doesn't increment by 1 each time, only ever making the parameter equal 2, which isn't what I want

Comment: @FesteringDoubt ensure there is an element with **id** attribute _addWhereButton_ in the DOM, like in the snippet example above - if not, then you will see that error message